# todos array at index 1 always get changed and the array doesn't move further - React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am Creating a Todo-List using typescript-react and my code doesn't seem to work.

App.tsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  let id = 0;
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  let todos: string[] = ["Arbit"];

  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    todos.push(todoInput);
    console.log(todos)
    setTodoInput("");
    id += 1;
    // console.log(todos);
    // console.log(todos[id])
    // console.log(e.target[0].value);
    // todos.push(e.target[0].value);
    // console.log(e)
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={todoInput}
          onChange={(e) => setTodoInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={id}>{todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The todos array doesn't push the todoInput. Instead, it omits todos[1].
I am creating my app in a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react functions you have to use hooks in order to retain the state during re-renders. In this case, you need to turn your `todos` array into a `const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState()` and update it using the `setTodos` function in a functional way.

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  // also use useState for ids
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(0);
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, todoInput]);
    console.log(todos)
    setTodoInput("");
    setId(id + 1);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you need to make the array a state too:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  let id = 0;
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(["Arbit"]);

  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    todos.push(todoInput);
    console.log(todos)
    setTodoInput("");
    setTodos(todos);
    id += 1;
    // console.log(todos);
    // console.log(todos[id])
    // console.log(e.target[0].value);
    // todos.push(e.target[0].value);
    // console.log(e)
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={todoInput}
          onChange={(e) => setTodoInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={id}>{todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm sorry if it doesn't work.